# What did Calypso say after Barbossa asked for her help?

Tags: pirates-of-the-caribbean, at-worlds-end

In *Pirates of the Caribbean: At World's End*, after Calypso is released and grows into a giant, Barbossa asks her to destroy the East India Trading Company who he tells her that they believe to be her masters (as Calypso is the Sea and Beckett believed himself Master of the Sea).

After a short moment of silence Calypso starts saying something, almost angry, before becoming a mass of crabs and returning to the sea. It's then when the winds pick up and a maelstrom forms which given the timing we can assume was her doing.

What was Calypso saying before she became the crabs?

Answer (score 2):

(At around 1h 55 mins) Prior to dissolving into a swarm of crabs, Calypso shouts a French incantation, which in the script reads: "Malfaiteur en Tombeau, Crochir l'Esplanade, Dans l'Fond d'l'eau!". This roughly means "Across all the waters, find the path to he who wrongfully entombed me!"

https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0449088/trivia?ref_=m_tt_trv_trv

Answer (score 1):

> Barbossa: Calypso, I come before you as a servant, humble and contrite. I have fulfilled me vow, and now ask your favor. Spare meself, me ship, me crew, but unleash your fury upon those who dare pretend themselves your masters, or mine.
>
> [Tia roars ‘My fishes’ and then some unintelligible words. She turns into a bunch of crabs that fall overboard]

[Fandom](http://transcripts.wikia.com/wiki/Pirates_of_the_Caribbean:_At_World%27s_End)